# Lots of "COMMIT;" in the PostgreSQL log of slow queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to optimize the *PostgreSQL* 9.1 database for a Rails app I am developing. In *postgresql.conf* I have set

```
log_min_duration_statement = 200
```

I then use *PgBadger* to analyze the log file. The statement which, by far, takes up most of the time is:

```
COMMIT;
```

I get no more information than this and I am very confused as to what statement this is. Does anyone know what I can do to get more detailed information about the COMMIT queries? All other queries show the variables used in the statement, SELECT, UPDATE etc. But not the COMMIT queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COMMIT` is perfectly valid statement which purpose is to commit currently pending transaction. Because of nature of what it really does - making sure that data is really flushed to disk, it is likely to take most of the time.

How can you make your app work faster?
Right now, it is likely that your code is using so called auto-commit mode - that is, every statement is implicitlly `COMMIT`'ted.
If you explicitly wrap bigger blocks into `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` ... `COMMIT;` blocks, you will make your app work much faster and reduce number of commits.
Good luck!

Comment: Although very accurate, please do keep in mind that wrapping in a transaction does alter the working of your application, as one error would mean nothing is saved to disk!

Comment: When running with AutoCommit turned on, you will NOT see COMMIT statements in the log. AutoCommit is most likely turned off and EVERY query is being explicitly wrapped in a transaction block.  That will make it more difficult to diagnose exactly what queries are resulting in long running syncs without turning on full logging.

Comment: Thanks! I will look for possibilites to wrap queries into bigger blocks.

Answer (score 10):

As @mvp notes, if `COMMIT` is slow the usual reason is slow `fsync()`s because every transaction commit must flush data to disk - usually with the fsync() call. That's not the only possible reason for slow commits, though. You might:

- have slow fsync()s as already noted
- have slow checkpoints stalling I/O
- have a `commit_delay` set - I haven't verified that delayed commits get logged as long running statements, but it seems reasonable

If fsync() is slow, your best option is to re-structure your work so you can run it in fewer larger transactions. A reasonable alternative can be to use a `commit_delay` to group commits; this will group commits up to improve overall throughput but will actually slow individual transactions down.

Better yet, fix the root of the problem. Upgrade to a RAID controller with battery backed write-back cache or to high-quality SSDs that're power-fail safe. See, ordinary disks can generally do less than one fsync() per rotation, or between 5400 and 15,000 per minute depending on the hard drive. With lots of transactions and lots of commits, that's going to limit your throughput considerably, especially since that's the *best case* if all they're doing is trivial flushes. By contrast, if you have a durable write cache on a RAID controller or SSD, the OS doesn't need to make sure the data is actually on the hard drive, it only needs to make sure it's reached the durable write cache - which is *massively* faster because that's usually just some power-protected RAM.

It's possible fsync() isn't the real issue; it could be slow [checkpoints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-CHECKPOINTS). The best way to see is to check the logs to see if there are any complaints about checkpoints happening too frequently or taking too long. You can also enable [`log_checkpoints`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CHECKPOINTS) to record how long and how frequent checkpoints are.

If checkpoints are taking too long, consider tuning the bgwriter completion target up (see the docs). If they're too frequent, increase `checkpoint_segments`.

See [Tuning your PostgreSQL server](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I will consider moving the database-server to an SSD-disc

Comment: @ollak If you do, make sure you get one of the few (sadly expensive) ones that has a reliable write-cache. Many of them will hopelessly corrupt your data on sudden power loss. You don't want that. You need an SSD with a proper supercapacitor, backup cap array, battery, or other power protection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to log every query for a couple of days and then see what is going on in the transaction before the COMMIT statement.

> log_min_duration_statement = 0